# Java thread-hopping or inter-thread communication

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a simple model-view-controller program. The model needs to be updated periodically, so the controller has a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor that launches a Runnable with the required periodicity. The model's methods would be needed to be called within this Runnable.

Since the model is not thread-safe —and I would like to avoid having to make it thread-safe—, all the model's methods have to be called from the same thread in order to avoid concurrency problems.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Immutable model and thread confinement ?

Comment: *"I would like to avoid having to make it thread-safe"* - can you elaborate on why?

Comment: Do they actually have to be called from *the same thread* every time, or just by *one single thread at a time*?

Comment: You might be able to queue up tasks that need to be performed on the model and have a single-thread consumer of that queue that updates the model.

Comment: @MatthiasMeid: "one single thread at a time", of course.

Comment: @RobHruska: Because I'm only using concurrency to implement a simple timer and ensuring that everything is thread-safe adds a layer of complexity to the program.

Comment: But Robs proposal is much easier than making it thread safe. He makes sure there **is** just one thread.

Comment: @Fildor my answer above was an answer to Rob's first comment. I actually thought of something similar to and actually sort of like Rob's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a wrapper class with the same interface as the model. The wrapper class delegates calls to the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

You say it's a Java MVC program... does that mean you're synchronizing with the GUI thread? In that case you'd want to call SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() or SwingUtilities.invokeLater() on your Runnable. That would run it on the GUI thread and avoid threading issues with the view.

Are there other, non-GUI, methods that also update the model?

Comment: "Are there other, non-GUI, methods that also update the model?" -No. But isn't it just a bit dirty having invokeLater() calls around every model method invocation?

Comment: Your other alternative is running things in a SwingWorker. That avoids the invokeLater at the expense of structuring your calls and updates in the SwingWorker structure.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to synchronize on the model instance:

```
synchronized(myModel) {
  // periodical view update
}
```

It is, however, not *best practice* to synchronize a non-private object. So there is a good chance you'll get better ideas.